# DataSourceRealm not working with Tomcat 8.5.24, Spring and Maven in Netbeans

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, authentication, netbeans

I've been a while trying to find the solution for this error but I couldn't find any solution...

I'm using Maven in Netbeans to create a web application and I want to introduce a very simple user registration/log in. So I have created the database with Derby like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    usuario     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    clave       VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 
);

CREATE TABLE Roles (
    usuario     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    rol         VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

And then I have created the Realm, as Apache Tomcat's documentation says, in my **context.xml**

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="true" path="/GestionScout">
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm" 
         dataSourceName="jdbc/GestionScout" 
         localDataSource="true" 
         roleNameCol="rol" 
         userCredCol="clave" 
         userNameCol="usuario" 
         userRoleTable="roles" 
         userTable="users"/>

  <Resource auth="Container" 
            driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" 
            maxActive="8" 
            name="jdbc/GestionScout" 
            password="dani" 
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
            url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/scout" 
            username="dani"/>

</Context>
```

And last I have defined the security constrains in **web.xml** so when you want to access the profile, if you are not logged in, then the log-in form is loaded and asks you for your log-in info. The problem is that, even though the webapp has access to the derby database (I have proved that), after introducing right log-in info it redirects to */inicio/admin/j_security_check* and doesn't do anything, it's like I introduced wrong info...

I have read that it can be a problem with Tomcat 8+ so I had to write some CredentialHandler into the Realm, but it doesn't work neither. Every tutorial in internet says that I have to put the Realm in some **server.xml** file, but I doesn't have any of that because I am using Spring...

Any help so far? :(

Answer (score 1):

As you have probably realised by now if you are using Spring Security you do not need to configure a DataSourceRealm (container managed security).

For the benefit of anyone who is searching for a solution to broken authentication after upgrading to Tomcat 8.5...

I was having a problem with legacy app that uses Tomcat container managed security (a DataSourceRealm). As of Tomcat 8.5 you have to specify a CredentialHandler. We use SHA-1 (it is rather old) to encrypt the passwords stored in the database. This meant replacing digest=sha with

in the  which FWIW is defined in ../webapp/META-INF/context.xml rather than /conf/server.xml. Only this app uses container managed authentication

Answer (score 0):

Basically this can be fixed by adding a nested [CredentialHandler](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/credentialhandler.html) like this:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"...>
 <CredentialHandler 
        className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler" 
        algorithm="MD5" />
</Realm>
```

Consider to use salted hash and more iterations to improve security.

Further information here (please don't complain when the link is dead): http://people.apache.org/~schultz/ApacheCon%20NA%202016/Seamless%20Upgrades%20for%20Credential%20Security%20in%20Apache%20Tomcat.pdf